# how can I get the path where npm global packages are located from inside a js file

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

how can I get the path where npm global packages are located from inside a js file

if I exec:

```
const root = require('child_process').execSync('npm root -g').toString().trim()
require('child_process').exec('npm root -g', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout)
});
```

first line hangs forever, and second line prints an object not the output from command (it works for other commands like dir or ls)

what I would like to achive is something like:

`require(root + '/globally_intalled_package/cli/cli')`

Comment: can't you just install the package you need locally? (you can do both btw)

Comment: the other package only seems to work when installed globally

Comment: also, I forgot to say this .js is a global package/command